# function app startup from scratch (not using the FunctionsStartup)

Tags: azure, dependency-injection, azure-functions

I need to use Startup.cs that doesn't inherit from FunctionsStartup.  My program looks like this..

```
public class Program
{
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
}

public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) => Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration(x =>
    {
        var environmentName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");

        var assembly = typeof(HostBuilderExtensions).Assembly;

        x.AddEmbeddedJsonFile(assembly, "sharedSettings.json")
            .AddEmbeddedJsonFile(assembly, $"sharedSettings.{environmentName}.json", true)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{environmentName}.json", true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables()
            .Build();
    })
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
    .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(x =>
    { 
        x.UseStartup<Startup>();
        });
}
```

My startup looks like this...

```
public class Startup 
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
    private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _environment;

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IWebHostEnvironment environment)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
        _environment = environment;
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
        services.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();

        var builder = services.ConfigureApp(_configuration)
            .AddDatabase<ApplicationContext>()
            .AddAutomapperProfilesFromAssemblies()
            .AddCaching()
            .AddMyDependencies()
            .AddStripeDependencies();
    }
    
    public void Configure(WebJobsBuilderContext builder)
    {
        // this isn't registered... throwing error
    }
}
```

In the configure method, Im not getting any FunctionApp services injected into the method.. they need to be registered i assume, but not sure how..

Comment: Few important questions to establish a context.: what is the version of the `TargetFramework` in `.csproj`, what is the version of `AzureFunctionsVersion` in `.csproj`, what is the value of `FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME` in `local.settings.json`?

Answer (score 1):

**Important to know**

There are different runtime models:

1. `Azure Functions in-process` (`.NET 6 class library`, `.NET Framework 4.8 class library`).
2. `Azure Functions isolated` (`.NET 6 Isolated`, `.NET 8 Isolated`).
3. `ASP.NET Core 5`.
4. `ASP.NET Core 6`, `ASP.NET Core 8`.

In your code snippet you have a mix of `Azure Functions in-process`, `Azure Functions isolated`, and `ASP.NET Core` models.

Instead, you should use only modern `Azure Functions isolated` model.

---

Few notes besides the answer:

1. The assembly `typeof(HostBuilderExtensions).Assembly` can't contain any `sharedSettings.json`. What are you trying to achieve there?

   If it is your custom library, in general, libraries shouldn't have any runtime configuration. Only the runnable application can have config. So, you shouldn't do it this way. You should have configuration files in the Azure Function app itself.
2. `ConfigureWebHostDefaults` configures a WebHost, not a FunctionsWorker. It is from `ASP.NET Core`, not `Azure Functions`. You shouldn't use it in your case.

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/generic-host

3. You shouldn't call `x.Build()` for `IConfigurationBuilder()` in `.ConfigureAppConfiguration()`. Your job is only add configuration provider. `ConfigurationBuilder` is built later when the Host is built by the `HostBuilder`.
4. There is no `WebJobsBuilderContext` anymore. It is from an old `in-process` model of .NET 6 Azure Functions. New `Azure Functions isolated` model (`.NET 6 Isolated`, `.NET 8 Isolated`) use Azure Functions Worker instead.

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-class-library
>
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide
>
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide#benefits-of-isolated-worker-process

---

*I'm answering in the context of Azure Functions isolated model (both `.NET 6 Isolated` and `.NET 8 Isolated`).*

There is no `Startup` class in `Azure Functions Isolated` (`ASP.NET Core` also doesn't have it anymore).

> 1. Former `Startup` in Azure Functions was derived from `FunctionsStartup`.
> 2. In a former `Startup` class from ASP.NET Core 5 there were two methods:
>
>    - `.ConfigureServices()` to configure DI (Dependency Injection).
>    - `.Configure()` to configure how the app responds to HTTP requests.
>
> In `ASP.NET Core 6` and `ASP.NET Core 8` there is no such methods anymore. Anyway, they were never relevant to `Azure Functions` models.

**Answer**

So, to achieve what you want to achieve, you should do the following:

1. To configure DI in `Azure Functions Isolated` model, you should use `.ConfigureServices()` method of the `HostBuilder`.

   > https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide#dependency-injection

   ```cs
   // Program.cs

   var host = new HostBuilder()
       // Alternative for the former `Startup.ConfigureServices()`
       .ConfigureServices(services =>
       {
           services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
           services.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();
       })
   ```
2. To configure middleware (if needed) in `Azure Functions Isolated` model, you should use `.ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()` method of the `HostBuilder`.

   > https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide#middleware

   ```cs
   // Program.cs

   var host = new HostBuilder()
       // Alternative for the former `Startup.Configure()`
       .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults(workerApplication =>
       {
           workerApplication.UseMiddleware<ExceptionHandlingMiddleware>();
           workerApplication.UseMiddleware<CustomMiddleware>();
       })
       .Build();
   ```

Comment: Although I agree with most of @Vlad's notes, he could have added that Program.cs is where the code he shows on 1. and 2. should go. Its content is similar to what the Startup.cs used to contain.